2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #2 on Substrate and Polkadot has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:


They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Congratulations @bkchr and @AurevoirXavier!
Thank you @Nuke for your help in the past :)
Let's continue to grow and foster this community.
